# Group users by purchases with ML in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, machine-learning, market-basket-analysis

I have a dataset of purchases

```
user_id, item_id
==================
1, 1
1, 2
1, 3
2, 2
2, 3
3, 8
3, 9
4, 8
4, 9
```

From this, I want to create some "clusters". From the data, it seems that user 1 and 2 are very similar and user 3 and 4 are very similar.

I don't know how I can create this analysis with machine learning in Python.

I guess it, for instance, could be distances with like

```
   1, 2, 3, 4
1, -, ?, ?, ?
2, ?, -, ?, ?
3, ?, ?, -, ?
4, ?, ?, ?, -
```

so I can determine how similar each user is to other users.

What I want is to determine if various users belong to certain groups based on their purchases. For instance, if some users buy many baby-related items, they might be new mothers/fathers, while users who buy many software-related books might be IT professionals/students.

Comment: Have you tried k-means clustering?

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses SciKit Learn:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

#Putting in your data
data = {'user': [1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4], 'item':[1,2,3,2,3,8,9,8,9]}

#Turning it into a DataFrame in Pandas (useful if you have more than one attribute in real life    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#For this specific example you have to do a reshape because it is a single attribute you are putting in 
item = np.array(data['item']).reshape(-1,1)

#Using sklearn's kmeans to create 2 clusters... you can create as many as you want, but for this example that is the number that made sense
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2)
kmeans.fit(item)

#This is so you can see the labels.  You can append the labels to the dataframe created earlier if you'd like
print(kmeans.labels_)
```

The labels are: `[0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]`.  So, group 0 and group 1.  These are in the order entered.  So, Users 1 & 2 are in group 0 and Users 3 & 4 are in group 1.

Comment: Thanks! Seems k-means works, but doesn't this code cluster the transactions rather than the users? I would like to say to which cluster each user belongs. I am not sure if it's possible, but this seems to be very close!

Comment: it is clustering the user by their transaction... i.e., users 1 and 2 are clustered together because they bought similar items... likewise users 3 and 4 are clustered together because they bought items that were similar.

I guess you could turn it around and say that items 1/2/3 are similar because they were bought by users 1/2 and items 8/9 are similar because they were bought by users 3/4.  To do this, just change the data['item'] to data['user']...